# Linq Query Nested select + distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a really hard time converting this query to LINQ.

```
select fk, count(*)
from (
    select distinct fk, attribute1, attribute2
    from table
) a
group by fk
having count(*) > X
```

I need each distinct combination of fk, attr1, attr2 grouped by fk only where count is bigger than x (parameter).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your nested query:

```
var query= db.Table.Select(e=>new {e.FK, e.Attribute1, e.Attribute2}).Distinct();
```

After that, you can do this:

```
int x=10;
var result= from e in query
            group e by e.FK into g
            let count=g.Count()
            where count>x
            select new{FK=g.Key, Count=count};
```

When you call, for example, the `ToList` method, is when those queries are going to be executed against your DB and the resulted elements are going to be loaded into the memory.

```
var elements=result.ToList();
```

Merging all, you could also do this:

```
int x=10;
var elements=(from e in db.Table.Select(e=>new {e.FK, e.Attribute1, e.Attribute2}).Distinct()
             group e by e.FK into g
             let count=g.Count()
             where count>x
             select new{FK=g.Key, Count=count}).ToList();
```

Comment: A did it slightly different but this lead me to my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement `IComparable`, `IComparer` or pass `IEqualityComparer` or some other way to ensure `Distinct()` works across your class' properties, but here's the essential linq:

```
var result = (from t in tableList.Select(t => new { fk, attr1, attr2 }).Distinct()
              group t by t.fk into g
              select new { fk = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
             .Where(t => t.Count > X)
             .ToList();
```

this uses an anonymous type as the equivalent of 'select fk, attribute1, attribute2' but that may make it harder to implement Distinct().

By default `Distinct()` does an object-level compare (are the two instances the same instance) rather than a value-level compare (do they have the same value).